# Embedded Jetty forward servlet response to JSP

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, forwarding, embedded-jetty

Using Embedded Jetty I am trying to get a very simple servlet to forward to JSP page once the servlet doGet() has executed. However instead of reaching the JSP it simply recursively forwards to the same doGet() which is calling the forward.

Im very new to this stuff but its like it either cant find the JSP and instead maps to the only servlet that it can find or else I'm not registering the JSP or something.  please help.

My code is as follows...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class RunHelloServlet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(contextHandler);

    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()), "/*");
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloServlet() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String par1 = request.getParameter("par1");
        request.setAttribute("key", par1);
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        catch (ServletException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

My JSP located at .\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="javascript" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hp.it.kmcs.search</groupId>
  <artifactId>JettyTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JettyTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
    <jettyVersion>7.2.0.v20101020</jettyVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0.RC1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- This plugin is needed for the servlet example -->
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution><goals><goal>java</goal></goals></execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.hp.it.kmcs.JettyTest.RunHelloServlet</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I see you have a pom.xml.  I believe that is from Maven or something right?  At any rate, if you have a web.xml you should post that too.

Comment: no im not using any filters or least Im not aware of any.  i havn't any web.xml but was under the impression that with jetty i didn't necessarily need one

Comment: no web.xml.  I was under the impression (maybe wrong) that with embedded jetty i might not need one.  The servlet starts and accepts the request initially which made me believe that I was right in this assumption.  However as things get more complex it might be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've mapped `HelloServlet` so that it handles almost *every* request.  When you try to forward the request from `HelloServlet` to `/result.jsp`, Jetty matches the path `/result.jsp` to `/*` and so forwards the request right back to `HelloServlet` (which forwards it to `/result.jsp` and so on recursively).

You should make your servlet mapping more restrictive (e.g. `/hello` instead of `/*`).

Furthermore, since your .jsp file is in WEB-INF, you should be forwarding to `/WEB-INF/result.jsp`.

Comment: That mapping seemed to do work thanks.  Its no longer running recursively however it doesn't seem to be finding the jsp file.  Browser says cant find /WEB-INF/result.jsp.  Not quite sure why.

Comment: @robsbobs, I've never dealt with running a Jetty server from `main`.  As noted in the comments to your question, most Java web apps have a `web.xml` file to take care of the mappings and are deployed to an already running web server.  However, I suspect that you may need to tell Jetty where to find the WEB-INF directory.  Perhaps it's not even loading it.

Comment: youre probably right.  ill look into it.  Thats for the response.